# Start Exploring Wave Analytics- The 'Trailhead_Data_Manager' app was not found.

Tags: einstein-analytics, trailhead, training

Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
The 'Trailhead_Data_Manager' app was not found. Please follow the requirements and ensure the wave enabled org is setup correctly.

I have created the new credential for Wave Analytics with a Developer Edition org
In trail head challenge, it throwing an error as mentioned above.

Can any one guide me how to integrate this.

Any thoughts? I'd like to complete this trail and to progress to the next unit.

Hi guys - do you have any instructions on how to complete this challenge - I've tried everything and still no resolution.

I created a whole new email account and a new playground but still cannot get the wave app running.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks so much!
Kalina

Answer (score 1):

Many Trailhead users have had this problem.

I clicked on this [link](http://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/wave-de) to create a new Analytics Developer account. 
[image]

I didn't know how to link it to my existing Trailhead Playground account so I created a new one. Then I used this [article](https://force.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/2896953-trailhead-self-service-account-merge) to help me merge my two playgrounds so all my badges and points are in one account.

[image]

~Daniel

Comment: Can you please include any relevant content from those cited resource if they answer the question? Also if you could please remove the bashing of Salesforce and stick to the facts, that would hugely improve this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Adrian,

Bashing is a pretty strong word to use in this case and inaccurate. My critical comments of Salesforce weren't violent in nature or intent, which is pretty much what bashing means. I did not name-call or degrade Salesforce. My comments were factual, but I still removed them lest others also get the wrong impression. The issue of creating and linking an Analytics Developer account for new users is unnecessarily time consuming and frustrating. I searched a long time for a solution and couldn't find one, which is why I posted a solution here. Have a great day, Adrian!

Comment: I appreciate that. Frustrating as it may be that aspect is somewhat subjective, and hardly constructive. This answer is much improved. Since your edit I find this post high quality and useful. +1

Comment: I agree with what was written and now removed.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce now gives you the ability to connect the Developer Analytics Org under the Selected Sandbox, above the Check answer button.

1. Create the Analytics Dev Org, wait for it to generate. Then Login.
2. Once you login, click "Connect an Org" and your analytics user will show up to select.

I spent an hour trying to figure this out.